# SQL: Inner and Left Join with The multi-part identifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two query like this;

```
SELECT  j.ID, j.Pkey, j.SUMMARY, j.CREATED, j.RESOLUTIONDATE
        ,j2.SUMMARY, j2.CREATED, j2.RESOLUTIONDATE, j3.SUMMARY, j3.CREATED, j3.RESOLUTIONDATE
FROM Jira.jiraissue As j
INNER JOIN Jira.issuelink i
    ON i.SOURCE =j.ID and i.SEQUENCE = 0
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2
    ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID
LEFT JOIN Jira.issuelink i2 
    ON i2.SOURCE = j.ID  and i2.SEQUENCE = 1
LEFT JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j3 
    ON i2.DESTINATION = j3.ID
```

This works great. But when I try to implement (after inner join part) to another query, I getting an error.

```
  SELECT A.pkey as KREDİ, A.SUMMARY , B.pname AS STATU, D.Sorumlu AS SORUMLU, A.CREATED, A.RESOLUTIONDATE, dbo.CUSTVAL(11931, A.ID, 'S') AS BAYİ, dbo.GetLastStatuTime(A.ID) AS SON_STATU_TAR,j2.SUMMARY, j2.CREATED,j2.UPDATED, j2.RESOLUTIONDATE, j3.SUMMARY, j3.CREATED, j3.UPDATED, j3.RESOLUTIONDATE
FROM Jira.jiraissue A, jira.issuestatus B, AspNetServicesDB.dbo.STATU_MAP D
INNER JOIN Jira.issuelink i
    ON i.SOURCE = A.ID and i.SEQUENCE = 0
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2
    ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Jira.issuelink i2 
    ON i2.SOURCE = A.ID  and i2.SEQUENCE = 1
LEFT JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j3 
    ON i2.DESTINATION = j3.ID
WHERE A.issuestatus = B.ID
AND 'BAŞARAN OTOMOTİV' = dbo.CUSTVAL(11931, A.ID, 'S')
AND B.pname = D.JiraStatu collate Turkish_CS_AI
AND A.issuetype != 11
```

I only change `j.ID` to `A.ID`. The error message is;

```
The multi-part identifier "A.ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 
The multi-part identifier "A.ID" could not be bound.
```

I don't understand why. A means `Jira.jiraissue` table has `ID` column. Why `j.ID` works in first query but doesn't work `A.ID` in second query?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the where clause?

Comment: YOu should not ever be using implicit syntax and espcaially not when combined with explicit syntax.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't understand what you try to explain. Can you explain with more detail?

Comment: never use comma joins, they do not work correctly when combined with explicit joins. They are a SQL antipattern and you shouldreplece them any time you see them and never write one again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the multi-table from clause in your second query:

```
FROM Jira.jiraissue A, jira.issuestatus B, AspNetServicesDB.dbo.STATU_MAP D
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2 ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID
```

This gets executed as:

```
FROM Jira.jiraissue A, (
    jira.issuestatus B, (
        AspNetServicesDB.dbo.STATU_MAP D
        INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2 ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID 
    )
)
```

At the innermost level, `A` is not defined, so you get an error.

Comment: All type of `JOIN`'s working like this? Or just `INNER JOIN` ? Can you show me a page or link that can explain all JOIN is how they executed ?